# How to update price where value of rows exist in value of column in sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, cursors

i want to update column p1 but p1 same product.

update column p1 where example g6-1se in C1 exist in column name and update value null in column p1 in rows g6-1se by value p1 in row g6-1sr.

in rows 1 , read g6-1 and search in column name and update column p1 if exist. after read g6-1sr and search Until you reach the finish line in row 1 column c1 , Then pointer,point to the line before update is not null column p1.

**tbl before update:**

```
    +-------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
    | id    | Name        | C1                                            | P1    |
    +-------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
    | 29214 | g6-1sr      | g6-1, g6-1sr, g6-1se,g6-1se12,g6-1se1         | 28000 |
    | 29215 | g6-1se      | g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,  | null  |
    | 29226 | g6-1sf      | g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,  | null  |
    | 29237 | g6-1se1     | g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,  | null  |
    | 29248 | g6-1se12    | g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,  | null  |
    | 29259 | Nkg6-1se    | g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,  | null  |
    | 29269 | N56-1341se  | N56-11, N56-1341se, N56-1100, N56-1348se,     | 32000 |
    | 29270 | N56-1348se  | N56-11, N56-21, N56-1100, N56-2980,           | null  |
    | 29271 | F566 1341se | g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,  | 38000 |
    +-------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
```

**tbl after update:**

```
    +-------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
    | id    | Name        | C1                                            | P1    |
    +-------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
    | 29214 | g6-1sr      | g6-1, g6-1sr, g6-1se,g6-1se12,g6-1se1         | 28000 |
    | 29215 | g6-1se      | g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,  | 28000 |
    | 29226 | g6-1sf      | g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,  | null  |
    | 29237 | g6-1se1     | g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,  | 28000 |
    | 29248 | g6-1se12    | g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,  | 28000 |
    | 29259 | Nkg6-1se    | g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,  | null  |
    | 29269 | N56-1341se  | N56-11, N56-1341se, N56-1100, N56-1348se,     | 32000 |
    | 29270 | Asus N56-1348se  | N56-11, N56-21, N56-1100, N56-2980, N56-2| 32000 |
    | 29271 | F566 1341se | g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,  | 38000 |
    +-------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
```

> try with cursor but not successfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check it: dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=704040df4ea92bc698927f20b81f5401)

Basically, get all rows where P1 is null, and join its with all rows that have a P1 value and where name like c1.

**Using LIKE**

```
UPDATE     t1 
SET        P1 = t2.P1
FROM       tbl1 t1
INNER JOIN tbl1 t2 
ON         t2.P1 IS NOT NULL 
AND        t2.c1 LIKE '%' + t1.Name + '%'
WHERE      t1.P1 IS NULL;

|   id|Name       |C1                                          |   P1|
|----:|:----------|:-------------------------------------------|----:|
|29214|g6-1sr     |g6-1, g6-1sr, g6-1se,g6-1se12,g6-1se1       |28000|
|29215|g6-1se     |g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,|28000|
|29226|g6-1sf     |g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,|     |
|29237|g6-1se1    |g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,|28000|
|29248|g6-1se12   |g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,|28000|
|29259|Nkg6-1se   |g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,|     |
|29269|N56-1341se |N56-11, N56-1341se, N56-1100, N56-1348se,   |32000|
|29270|N56-1348se |N56-11, N56-21, N56-1100, N56-2980,         |32000|
|29271|F566 1341se|g6-1, g6-2, g6-1000, g6-1980,       g6-1230,|38000|
```

**Using dbo.SplitCompare() function**

```
UPDATE     t1 
SET        P1 = t2.P1
FROM       tbl1 t1
INNER JOIN tbl1 t2 
ON         t2.P1 IS NOT NULL 
AND        dbo.SplitCompare(t2.C1, t1.Name) = 1
WHERE      t1.P1 IS NULL;
```

**Update**

Check it: dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c9bb74650262fb3670cf77fcd97114dd)

First, I've added a new function: **[dbo].[SplitCompare]**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Compares each item of a coma-delimited string (without trainling spaces), 
-- against @ToSearch.
--
-- Returns: (int)
--
--    1 - @ToSearch matches some item
--    0 - No matches found.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitCompare] (@List nvarchar(MAX), @ToSearch nvarchar(1024))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Item nvarchar(1024) = null;
    DECLARE @Result int = 0;

    WHILE LEN(@List) > 0
    BEGIN
        IF PATINDEX('%,%', @List) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@List, 0, PATINDEX('%,%', @List));
            SET @List = SUBSTRING(@List, LEN(@Item + ';') + 1, LEN(@List));
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @Item = @List;
            SET @List = NULL;
         END

    IF RTRIM(LTRIM(@Item)) = @ToSearch -- does it match?
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = 1;
        SET @List = '';
    END
    END

    RETURN @Result;

END
```

Second, according to OP requirement, I've implemented this solution using a CURSOR.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Use @LimitRows just to limit the number of rows to be updated each time 
-- the script is executed.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @LimitRows int = 100;
DECLARE @Id int, @Name nvarchar(2048), @P1 int;

-- only selects rows where P1 IS NULL
DECLARE CurPrices CURSOR
    FOR SELECT TOP (@LimitRows) Id, Name FROM #tbl1 WHERE P1 IS NULL;

OPEN CurPrices 
FETCH NEXT FROM CurPrices INTO @Id, @Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN

    SET @P1 = NULL;

    -- note: top (1)
    --
    SELECT   TOP (1) @P1 = t.P1
    FROM     tbl1 t
    WHERE    t.P1 IS NOT NULL
    AND      dbo.SplitCompare(t.C1, @Name) = 1
    ORDER BY Id;

    IF COALESCE(@P1,0) > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE #tbl1
        SET    P1 = @P1
        WHERE  Id = @Id;

        IF @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
           CLOSE CurPrices;
           DEALLOCATE CurPrices;
           RAISERROR('ERROR', 20, -1);
        END
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM CurPrices INTO @Id, @Name    
END

CLOSE CurPrices;
DEALLOCATE CurPrices;
```

The result is the same as the first command, but this one allow to limit the number of affected rows every time it is executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54736/discussion-between-mcnets-and-redarmy).